# C# ComboBox show names and use id's as values?

Tags: c#, database

I'm displaying data from a database in a ComboBox in C#.

So I have a database table with an id and the name of it.

Now I try to display the name in the ComboBox and use the id as value. I know the are some other questions about this but unfortunately it didn't solve it for me.

The code I used now is like this:

```
            lblId.Visible = false;
            txtId.Visible = false;

            cbType.Items.Clear();
            con.Open();
            cmd = "SELECT Type_id, Type FROM type";

            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd, con);
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            da.Fill(dt);

            foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
            {
                cbType.Items.Add(dr["Type_id"].ToString());
            }

            con.Close();
```

Here I only ask for the id but I found something like this:

```
            cbType.DataSource = dt;
            cbType.DisplayMember = "Type";
            cbType.ValueMember = "Type_id";
```

This displays the name.

But now I need to insert it into the database. For this I use the following code:

```
            string klant = txtKlant.Text;
            string kenteken = txtKenteken.Text;
            string type = cbType.SelectedItem.ToString();
            DateTime startdatum = dtpStartdatum.Value;
            DateTime einddatum = dtpEinddatum.Value;

            int result = 0;

            con.Open();

            cmd = "INSERT INTO reserveringen (Klant, Kenteken, Type_id, Startdatum, Einddatum) values(@Klant, @Kenteken, @Type_id, @Startdatum, @Einddatum)";
            command = new SqlCommand(cmd, con);

            command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Klant", klant));
            command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Kenteken", kenteken));
            command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Type_id", type));
            command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Startdatum", startdatum));
            command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Einddatum", einddatum));

            result = command.ExecuteNonQuery();

            if (result > 0)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("De reservering is toegevoegd.");

                txtKlant.Text = "";
                txtKenteken.Text = "";
                cbType.Items.Clear();
                dtpStartdatum.Value = DateTime.Now;
                dtpEinddatum.Value = DateTime.Now;

                con.Close();

                bekijkReserveringen();
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Er is iets misgegaan, de reservering is niet toegevoegd.");
                con.Close();
            }
```

But when I try to add it to the database I get te following error on *result = command.ExecuteNonQuery();*:
**Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value 'System.Data.DataRowView' to data type int.**

When I use type I talk about name of the id because it's called like this in the database.

If I insert it with the first block of code it works fine, but for the user I need to show the name.

So does someone know what the problem could be?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Welcome to SO! As a tip: sometimes less code is better. In your last code sample you use the variable `type` but you don't show how it gets populated. Can you rework your sample?

Comment: Thank you! I find it difficult to explain exactly what I mean :-). When I use `type` it means the name of the id (I used that because it's called like that in the database). I will put this in my question. And to be honest I'm not sure if I can rework it because it is a system where thing linked together.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `cbType.SelectedValue` instead of `SelectedItem` and you should correctly get the value.